# Rails 3 form error - wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am getting an error on my rails 3.2.16 form:

```
<%= form_for @group_member, :as => :group_member, :url => {:action=>'edit_group_member', :id=>@group, :person_id => @group_member.person_id} do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :person, @group_member.person_id %>
  <p><table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.check_box :admin %></td>
    <td><label for="group_member_admin">Group administrator (can modify members and most group properties)</label></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Cancel" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Then I get the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:   <%= hidden_field_tag :person, @group_member.person_id %>
5:   <p><table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
6:     <tr>
7:       <td><%= f.check_box :admin %></td>
8:       <td><label for="group_member_admin">Group administrator (can modify members and   most group properties)</label></td>
9:     </tr>
10:   </table></p>
```

Please help me discover what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Hm, looks all right to me. Could you add `<%= f.method(:check_box).source_location %>` and comment out the line with an error?

Comment: @BroiSatse then i get undefined method `source_location' for #<Method: ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#check_box>

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
:as => :group_member
```

from form_for .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I later realized that this issue was caused by custom code in a plugin that was overriding the helper methods. So, usually this code will work fine.

Certainly something for others to keep in mind if they are frantically trying to debug similar problems.